# How do I strip lines in python to allow for calculations with numbers in a list, pulled from a txt file?

Tags: python-3.x

I am opening a .txt file that lists the following numbers on separate lines:
86
92
77
83
96
once the file is written the numbers are added to a list in the main function, then the second function needs to find the average of the numbers in the list. The code needs to be able to handle numbers other than those in the original .txt file as this is how it will be graded. When I attempt to strip the list in order to gather the sum and then len, it supplies me with the following error:

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

If I use print(scores) after stripping, the values are listed as such:
['86', '92', '77', '83', '96']

I think the issue is the ' ' in the list, but can't seem to strip it.

This is my current code:

```
def main():
scores = []
f = open("scores.txt", 'r')
line_list = list(f.readlines())
i = 0
while i < len(line_list):
    scores.append(line_list[i])
    i += 1
f.close()
showscores(scores)
def showscores(scores):
index = 0
while index < len(scores):
    scores[index] = scores[index].strip('\n')
    index += 1
sum(scores)
```

`main()`

Comment: `scores = [int(line.strip()) for line in open('scores.txt')]`

Comment: Wow awesome, it works perfectly, I placed it under my second function and erased the second while loop. Then calculated the average. Amazing, thank you!

Comment: Just a note: you can't "strip" the quotes. What was printed was a representation of the data in the list. You don't change the representation; you change the underlying data by converting the strings to ints.

Answer (score 0):

```
file = open("scores.txt", "r") # Open the file
lines = file.readlines() # Break the file up into lines
scores = []
for line in lines: # Loop through the lines
    data = line.split() # Split the data at each space
    for item in data: # Loop through that data
        scores.append(int(item)) # Convert to int before adding to scores
file.close() # Close file
```